# where do I find the dotcall64 related arguments used by R's randomforest?

Tags: r, random-forest

Where can I obtain the relevant arguments for R's randomforest for which I need to provide signatures in dotcall64?

I have 14 million cases and about 20 predictors. I tried running randomforest on  my university's High Performance Computing cluster (unix). I got an error " long vectors (argument 24) are not supported in .C".
I have successfully run it for up to about 6 million cases. 
I just about know enough R to run statistical tests on PCs and clusters. I have no knowledge of C or how to obtain, read and edit any low level languages that randomforest is based on, if any.
thanks.

I am trying to see if there is an analogous solution based on this

[using long vectors in R with glmnet and dotCall64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599793/using-long-vectors-in-r-with-glmnet-and-dotcall64)

Comment: clarifying that i am doing a classification randomforest

Comment: Adding a bit of R code to illustrate your question would help.

Comment: **dotCall64** is illustrated/described in https://doi.org/10.1016/j.softx.2018.06.002